# Replication Framework for Mono

Tags: sqlite, mono, xamarin.ios, replication, xamarin.android

We are considering adopting MonoTouch and MonoDroid for building a cross platform business App.

This App will handle a local database that needs to be synchronized with a master database (only one way replication).

The only project remotely like what we are looking for is: http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/home. However, we are not that satisfied to run it as a service (and also it is for Objective-C and Java, not for Mono).

Synchronizing central databases to the local SQLite in the device seems a very common subject. It is strange that there is not some sort of framework for this (paid or opensource).

Rhomobile offers RhoConnect for that. Still not that suitable for us.

BTW: I know we can build it using web services and timestamp columns. I just would like to avoid the need to do that if possible.

So the question is: do you know of any framework/library or the like that could be used from MonoTouch and/or MonoDroid to sync the local database to a central database?

Thanks.

Comment: We have one of those. Give me 2 days to check, I guess we can GPL it (and would do so ofcourse)

Comment: Thanks. I also found [QuickConnect](http://www.quickconnectfamily.org/qcdbsync/more.html#) but it seems like a inactive project.

Comment: try this [siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/) i think that what i'm gonna use, i have the same situation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com) , it fully supports MonoDroid and MonoTouch and has SyncFramework provider which you can keep local db Sync-ed with SQLServer from server side.